# Using Configurable Map Viewer Attributes Table?

Tags: query, table, widget, configurable-map-viewer

I've created a CMV query widget that I am trying to link up with the Attribute Table  widget. The table tab is being created in the bottom pane but that's as far as I'm able to get. I'm unable to get the query to actually execute and I'm unsure of the reason. I have used the Search widget as my starting point.

In my executing function I have the following:

```
var query = {
    "layerID": "SelectOverlayData",
    "sublayerID": 1,
    "type": "spatial",
    "outFields": [
        "TMK",
        "TPL_ACRES",
        "owner",
        "B_al02"
    ],
    "outputSpatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100,
        "latestWkid": 3857
    },
    "spatialRelationship": "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
    "geometry": null,
    "where": "TPL_ACRES <= 40 AND B_al02 = 'Yes'"
};
```

and

```
var grid = {
    "minWidth": 50,
    "columns": [
        {
            "field": "TMK",
            "label": "Parcel ID",
            "width": 100
        },
        {
            "field": "TPL_ACRES",
            "label": "Acres",
            "width": 100
        },
        {
            "field": "owner",
            "label": "Owner",
            "width": 100
        },
        {
            "field": "B_al02",
            "label": ">>Protect farmlands",
            "width": 100
        }
    ],
    "sort": [
        {
            "attribute": "TMK",
            "descending": "ASC"
        }
    ],
    "defaultColumnWidth": 100,
    "columnHide": true,
    "columnReorder": true,
    "pagination": true,
    "paginationOptions": {
        "rowPerPage": 50,
        "previousNextArrows": true,
        "pagingLinks": 2,
        "pagingTextBox": true,
        "showLoadingMessage": true
    }
};
```

Into

```
        topic.publish(this.attributesContainerID + '/addTable', {
            title: layer.name,
            topicID: this.topicID,
            queryParameters: query,
            gridOptions: grid,
            idProperty: layer.idProperty
        });
```

The tab is created in the bottom pane with the rest of the Attribute Table widget but the query is never run (nothing in the Network tab of Chrome) and no records or columns ever appear in the table. No js errors. I must be missing something small.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance, your configuration looks correct. You can omit the `geometry` property for the query but that should not influence the success or failure.

The most common reason for the query not executing and not receiving an error message is that the url for the query is wrong or cannot be determined from the layer using layerID and sublayerID. I recommend that you use Chrome Dev Tools to step through the `executeQuery` (https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/blob/master/widgets/AttributesTable/_QueryMixin.js#L107) and `buildURL` (https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/blob/master/widgets/AttributesTable/_QueryMixin.js#L107) functions and see where it might be falling over.

The other possibility is that you have an incorrect field name and the QueryTask is returning an error. This error should be caught and appear as a growl in the `Growler` widget (Assuming you have that widget in your app).

Comment: So does the topic addTable publish to the topic executeQuery? It looks to me like the addTable topic adds the table and publishes to topic tableAdded and then that's it. Do I then need to publish to executeQuery?

Comment: No you do not need to publish the second topic.  I was referring to the executeQuery method.

Comment: So should this be published to executeQuery rather than addTable?            topic.publish(this.attributesContainerID + '/addTable', {
            title: layer.name,
            topicID: this.topicID,
            queryParameters: query,
            gridOptions: grid,
            idProperty: layer.idProperty
        });

Comment: No.  addTable will also execute the query if the query parameters are valid. Double check your parameters as I noted in my answer.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I'm new to the Dojo topic stuff and still trying to wrap my brain around that. I'm trying to follow the program flow from addTable through executeQuery so I can see where my queryParameters are not passing the test. I appreciate your time.

Comment: When the program gets to Table.js postCreate, this.queryParameters is the default null version of the queryParameters. Something must not be getting passed through to that point. It seems as though that would be next after adding the table, which is working.

Comment: Ok.  I'll walk through it myself when back at my computer to verify the parameters at that point in the flow.

Comment: Hey, I got it! In my publish to addTable above I had to change the "queryParameters" attribute to "queryOptions" and then nest my "queryParameters" as a sub-object within "queryOptions" then everything worked. That is not very clear in the README. It should say queryOptions.queryParameters. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct about the options. I will update the README documentation.

Comment: I have the table working a lot better. I have another issue though, I can't get the row select, zoom to work correctly. I've deduced that it doesn't matter which row I click on, the 'dgrid-select' event always returns the same row to the call back. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You need to include the unique id field like OBJECTID in your outFields and then the same field needs to also be the idProperty.

Comment: I've done that. Could it be because the OID is "OBJECTID_1" for this featureclass?

Comment: For some reason the row objects returned by the callback have the "id" attribute set to "undefined". Think that might be the cause?

Comment: Ah, for some reason this.idProperty in _GridMixin.js is set to default "FID" and not what it should be ("OBJECTID_1"). I must have a config error somewhere.

Comment: Ah, finally figured it out! The AttributeTable widget README.me should be edited for the queryOptions section. queryOptions.idProperty, queryOptions.queryParameters, queryOptions.linkedQuery, queryOptions.bufferParameters. I can see it now but I really did not get that at first read. It's all working!

Comment: The AttributesTable docs [README.md](https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/blob/master/widgets/AttributesTable/README.md#query-options) was updated a couple of days ago and should accurately reflect the various `queryOptions`.